# ¿ Que debo usar para no el ejecutar el código de un modulo cuando le requiero?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, test

Estoy corriendo test y en un modulo requiero de otro, pero hay código que no quiero que se ejecute.
Bien, yo utilizo "if (!parent) {} " que vi en un ejemplo, pero se sigue ejecutando todo el código del modulo al que llamo.
¿ Que condición debo usar para evitar el código que no deseo se ejecute ?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El código necesario es:

```
if (!module.parent) {}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta sería más valiosa con una explicación. Una pura línea de código no educa ni enseña.